# Distribution clean up job in transactional replication removed records but not files

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

Distribution clean up job ran without errors according to schedule, but I noticed that the snapshot files were not removed even if when created beyond `max_disretention` period. Records from `msrepl_commands` and `msrepl_transactions` were removed, but the files were not.

- `immediate_sync` = 1
- `max_disretention` = 72 hours

Comment: This sounds like a permission issue.  Have you granted the service accounts (SQL Engine and Agent on the distribution server) full access to the directory where the replication files live?

Answer (score 0):

the "immediate sync" option is the problem here. Unless you are regularly adding new subscribers every few hours, then this can be set to false and the snapshots are then cleared out after being applied.

```
exec sp_changepublication
          @publication=N'<publication_name>',
          @property=N'allow_anonymous',
          @value='false';
go

exec sp_changepublication
          @publication=N'<publication_name>',
          @property=N'immediate_sync',
          @value='false';
go
```

There is a lot of really good information about this here: http://www.replicationanswers.com/TransactionalOptimisation.asp

Comment: Tried this with no luck. I suspect records from Msrepl_commands somehow removed without touching files, after that those files keep forever.